# Python - How to delete all text files in a given directory

Tags: python

I would Like a way to delete all text files in a directory. There are other files in the directory as well so I would only like to delete the `.txt` files. How would I do this?

Comment: Could use grep too: `find | grep car | xargs rm -f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir, file))
```

EDIT: For clarity, fill in your own `dir` name -- do not use `dir` as variable names.

Comment: `dir` might not be the best name in `for file in os.listdir(dir):`. If I import `os` and run this code I get: `TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not builtin_function_or_method` because Pythons built-in function [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)  is used.

Answer (score -1):

You might combine [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) with [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) to get all `.txt` files deleted in current working directory as follow

```
import glob
import os
for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    os.remove(filename)
```